# Emberjs 1.8 handlebars "view select" set default value/prompt text with variable

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-1

I want to set a default value or prompt a text to my select dropdown, I have managed to get the correct content into the select, but I want to be able to have a default value that differs from the content, for example " select country " and then list the countries.

This is how the select looks like so far, and the testing variable looks like this: `testFillSelect: "Select Country..",`

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Countries:</label>
                    {{view "select2"
                           prompt="Select country.."
                           content=countries
                           optionValuePath="content.id"
                           optionLabelPath="content.name"
                           selectionBinding=testFillSelect
                           selection=countries.id
                           class="form-control"}}
                </div>
```

The problem is, the `selectionBinding` doesn't seem to work as it does nothing, and niether does the `prompt` unless it's a blankspace in a string. I have tried select and select2, didn't make any difference either.
Does anyone have any idea of how to do this properly?

Comment: I'm not sure, it has been a while, but I remember this being tricky back then. I think once I just added that text as a item to the actual array passed to `content`, and removed it as soon something else was selected, so people could not re-select it. Thats more a workaround tho.

Comment: @Lux It's really that complicated then.. Feels like it's something that should be extremely easy to do..

Comment: The select view was never really nice. It's also not a part of ember anymore. And with the upcoming of the add-on system we had good solutions for all use-cases. The problem is indeed your ancient ember version.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd just leave an answer here in case anyone stumbles upon the same problem in the future, with this ember version.

Inspired by [Lux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1458413/lux) comment, I passed an object as the first object in the content array instead, I did this using `unshiftObjects` which is supported by this ancient ember version believe it or not. (The first object is what is shown in the select if there's data in it & there's no prompt in the select view)

Code example of what I did:

```
this.set('countries', countries.unshiftObjects({id:-1, name:"Select country.."}));
```

And a validation that checks if a post is made with id -1 and in that case treat it as if nothing was selected.

Note that there are probably better ways to go about this & this is a workaround, but it's what worked for me :)